# Repository pattern questions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Lately, I implemented repository pattern and unit of work (using generic repository) because it helps unit testing. There are many tutorials which are in conflict with each other.

I have a few questions related to my code below:

- I currently have `IUnitOfWork/UnitOfWork` added as a scoped service in Startup.cs. I'm not quite sure whether it should be one instance (singleton) or new instance (scoped), or even transient.
- Did I miss to dispose anything else than `IDisposable`'s implementation in UnitOfWork?
- Anything else wrong with my repository pattern/UnitOfWork implementation?

IUnitOfWork.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SaveBees.Repositories
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IUserRepository Users { get; }
        IRoleRepository Roles { get; }

        Task<int> SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SaveBees.Repositories
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly SaveBeesContext _context;

        public UnitOfWork(SaveBeesContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        private IRoleRepository _roleRepository;

        public IRoleRepository Roles
        {
            get
            {
                if (_roleRepository == null)
                {
                    _roleRepository = new RoleRepository(_context);
                }

                return _roleRepository;
            }
        }

        private IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public IUserRepository Users
        {
            get
            {
                if (_userRepository == null)
                {
                    _userRepository = new UserRepository(_context);
                }

                return _userRepository;
            }
        }

        public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
        {
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        private bool _disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

IGeneralRepository.cs

```
using SaveBees.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SaveBees.Repositories
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null);
        Task<List<TEntity>> QueryAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null);
        Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null);
        Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null);
        Task AddAsync(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
        void Remove(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

GeneralRepository.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SaveBees.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SaveBees.Repositories
{
    public abstract class GenericRepository<TEntity, TContext> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, IEntity
        where TContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly TContext _context;

        public GenericRepository(TContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();

            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes(query);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<TEntity>> QueryAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes(query);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(int id, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();

            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes(query);
            }

            return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> SingleOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>> includes = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _context.Set<TEntity>();

            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes(query);
            }

            return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(filter);
        }

        public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            _context.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

IUserRepository.cs

```
using SaveBees.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SaveBees.Repositories
{
    public interface IUserRepository : IGenericRepository<User>
    {
        Task<User> GetByEmailAsync(string email);
    }
}
```

UserRepository.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using SaveBees.Models;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SaveBees.Repositories
{
    public class UserRepository : GenericRepository<User, SaveBeesContext>, IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(SaveBeesContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public async Task<User> GetByEmailAsync(string email)
            => await SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Email == email,
                e => e.Include(u => u.UserRoles)
                    .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role));
    }
}
```

IEntity.cs

```
namespace SaveBees.Data
{
    public interface IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're actually just adding another (imo unnecessary) layer of abstraction on top of the EF DbContext which already implements the Unit Of Work pattern, so imho, this is quite useless.  When you want to test your functionality, just use an inmem db for the unittests.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/387135/should-entity-framework-6-not-be-used-with-repository-pattern/387178#387178

Comment: So the whole Repository layer is pointless? Then why there are so many tutorials over it -.- And all of them are trying to explain why it is better to use it.

Comment: It is not pointless _in general_. It has its place. Just in conjunction with EF it is somewhat shooting yourself in the foot. There is an IMHO excellent discussion of all that in the answer I linked above.

Comment: Thanks, I read it and I agree. Thanks for the in-memory database idea too. However, let's say I'm using MongoDB. Then I would have to implement this logic. Can you still answer to my questions?

Comment: I know, you feel sad for all the code you just wrote and test. But frankly, you just dodge a bullet. Btw this may be what you are looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks, I will just revert back.

Comment: @xdtTransform That was in french. Here it is in en-us: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking?redirectedfrom=MSDN